# oauth2 without api key

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0

I'm dead lost :)

Goal is to logon to a web site that uses OAuth2. However the section I need to run, doesn't have an API associated with it. So I need to login, just using the username and password, and then navigate to the page in question and do a screen scrape to get my data.

I'm sure the problem isn't at the web site it's sitting at this keyboard. But i've searched for examples and tried a whole bunch of guesses, but nothing is working

Help would be gratefully accepted.

```
import sys
import requests
import oauth2 as oauth

r = requests.get(logon_url)
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=user, secret=password)
client = oauth.Client(consumer)
resp, content = client.request(r.url, "GET")
token_url = resp['content-location']

# At this point i'm lost i'm just guessing on the rest
# the next doesn't give an error but i'm sure it's wrong
resp2, content2 = client.request(token_url, 'GET')

# save the cookie, i do have a cookie but not sure what i have 
auth_token = resp['set-cookie']
```

Comment: with username and password you can login the same way as human do - using page with login form.

Comment: But then how do i connect the authorization to the next page request (i'm obviously lost here). I'm in python and so there isn't a browser running.

Comment: use `requests` (with `requests.Session()`) to do everything - get login form, POST your login and password, get next page, get data. But your script has to behave like browser - so use "Developer Tools" in Chrome or "Firebug" in Firefox to see what data is send from browser to server and from server to browser.

Comment: Thanks furas, that was just the hint i needed to get me going. Code is below and it's as simple as one would expect. Now it's on to pushing Java script buttons from inside of python.

Comment: if button use AJAX (XHR) to load some data then you can use `Developer Tools/Firbug` to see url used by AJAX (XHR) and use `requests` to get data directly  from this url.

Comment: btw: `requests` is created to send and receive data - it doesn't `"render"` page so it doesn't execute JavaScript code - so it can't push  button. `selenium` works in different way - it controls browser - so it can push buttons.

Comment: Furas, thanks for the pointer on the render, got selenium to work and i'ved downloaded my data. I may next try to operate my spreadsheet that uses pivot tables and the like from inside of python, but that might be a bridge too far. I'm trying to automate a function my wife has to do to produce reports and i need to make it as "user friendly" as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so many things, it's just a user error

code to get me to the page is so simple. And the following code does the trick. Thanks to Furas for the pointer.

```
    with requests.session() as s1:
         # get login form
         r = s1.get(logon_url)
         # post the username and password
         resp = s1.post(r.url,data=payload)
         # get the admin page
         resp2 = s1.get(page_url)
```